# exec not working with input redirection

Tags: scripts

**I am trying to use redirection operator with exec command to input data from the file, but it is throwing error**

```
sh-4.3$ cat test                                                                                                                                              
hi this is a test                                                                                                                                             
so wait                                                                                                                                                       
sh-4.3$ exec <test                                                                                                                                            
sh-4.3$ hi this is a test                                                                                                                                     
sh: hi: command not found                                                                                                                                     
sh-4.3$ so wait                                                                                                                                               
sh: so: command not found                                                                                                                                     
sh-4.3$ exit
```

Comment: by default it will be the stdin (file descriptor 0 ) so that i can use it directly for reading the file without using the filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crucial point isn't the redirection, but the content of your file. `exec` *executes* your file. That means, it looks at the content of your file and tries to run the commands written in it. But your file does not contain any commands that the shell knows about.

It comes across `hi`, but there's no such command. So it tells you that:

```
sh: hi: command not found
```

Then, it tries the next line. It reads 'so', but there's no such command. So it tells you that:

```
sh: so: command not found
```

If you want to hand over your file as input to a program, you need to bring that program into play somehow. Don't just throw the data to the shell and hope for it to figure out on its own what do with it ;)

Comment: so what is the syntax for assigning the stdin to the file for the current shell, so i can read from the file without using the filename.

Comment: I think the issue is that file descriptor `0` is already attached to the tty - so the contents of the file are simply read by the terminal immediately. If you want to use a file descriptor for reading data into some other process, you'd usually assign it to an unused descriptor such as `exec 3<file` and then read *that* e.g. in `bash` you can use the `-u` flag like `read -r -u3 line ... `. If your process can *only* read from stdin, then you will need to redirect `0` to another FD first and restore it after, I think.

Comment: You want some kind of program, tool, command to handle the data in your file, correct? So you need to call that program, tool, command or whatever it is. Some programs can take the path of an input file as an argument, for example `python my_python_program.py`. Others offer an option to read from a file instead of reading from stdin, for example `wget -i file_with_urls.txt`. If the program in question doesn't offer any of those, you can redirect stdin: `whatever_program < input_data.txt`. But it's quite hard to answer your question without knowing which program you want to hand the data to.

Comment: @steeldriver You're thinking too complicated, IMHO. You can redirect stdin to a file, so a program designed to read from stdin reads from that file instead. But you have to call that program in the first place, or else the shell doesn't have any idea what to do with the data (other than trying to execute anything that comes its way as commands). So `whatever_program < input_data.txt` works fine, as long as `whatever_program` reads from stdin.